# Pyside: How to clear all the widget in the QHBoxLayout?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, pyside

I want to clear all the widgets in a QHBoxLayout when click a button.How to solve this problem? Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to remove all widgets from layout?

Comment: yes,the widgets in the layout.

Comment: Did you read the documentation for `QBoxLayout`? Because there is a `removeWidget` method or a `takeAt` method which can be used to remove an item from the layout. There is no built-in method for removing all items. If you don't want to call `removeWidget` many times just replace the layout with a new instance.

Comment: This might also come in handy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21213853/pyside-how-to-delete-widgets-from-gridlayout/21214247?noredirect=1#comment31969840_21214247